# First and Second Order Derivate of the Function having summation sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have this function having a summation sequence in it
$$ f(x) =\frac {1} { \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k}} $$

How do I determine the first and second derivatives of the function with respect to x?

Comment: What are $x_k$?

Comment: There is no $x$ on the right side, so both derivatives are 0...

Comment: k is the subscript so i assume the terms are represented as $$x_1$$, $$ x_2$$ and so on up to $$x_k$$

Comment: Derivative with respect to ... what, Arslan?

Comment: Derivate With respect to x

Comment: If $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in E$ where $E$ is, say, a Banach space, then the derivative notion is unclear unless $n=1$ and $E=\mathbb{C}$. However, you can consider the differential $\mathrm{d}f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{k}}(x)\mathrm{d}x_k\in\mathcal{B}(E)$ and you are left with the only calculation of the partial derivatives.

Comment: And how are $x_1,\dots,x_k$ related to $x$, Arslan?

Comment: You've had two answers, Arslan, and a number of comments, and nothing to say. Please engage with people who are trying to help you.

Comment: Yes i got that. Have ticked marked the appropriate solution as well. Thanks All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the first derivative
$$\frac {\partial}{\partial x_p} \Bigg[ \dfrac {1} { \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k}}\Bigg]=\frac {\partial}{\partial x_p} \Bigg[ \dfrac {1} { \frac{1}{x_p}+C}\Bigg]=\frac {\partial}{\partial x_p}\Bigg[ \dfrac {x_p} { 1+Cx_p}\Bigg] $$since $$C=\sum _{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{x_k}+\sum _{k=p+1}^{n} \frac{1}{x_k}$$ does not depend on $x_p$

$$\frac {\partial}{\partial x_p} \Bigg[ \dfrac {1} { \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k}}\Bigg]=\frac{1}{(1+C x)^2}$$
$$\frac {\partial^2}{\partial x_p^2} \Bigg[ \dfrac {1} { \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k}}\Bigg]=-\frac{2 C}{(1+C x)^3}$$
$$\frac {\partial^3}{\partial x_p^3} \Bigg[ \dfrac {1} { \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k}}\Bigg]=\frac{6 C^2}{(1+C x)^4}$$
$$\frac {\partial^4}{\partial x_p^4} \Bigg[ \dfrac {1} { \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k}}\Bigg]=-\frac{24 C^3}{(1+C x)^5}$$ I am sure that you see the very clear pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean $f(\boldsymbol x) = \dfrac {1} { \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k}}$, where $\boldsymbol x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k)$.

**Hint.** Try small examples:

When $k=2$:
$$
\frac{\partial f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1} = \frac{1}{x_1^2 \left(\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}\right)^2}\\
\frac{\partial ^2f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1^2}=\frac{2}{x_1^4 \left(\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x_1^3 \left(\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}\right)^2}
$$
When $k=3$:
$$
\frac{\partial f(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{\partial x_1}=\frac{1}{x_1^2 \left(\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{x_3}\right)^2}\\
\frac{\partial ^2f(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{\partial x_1^2}=\frac{2}{x_1^4 \left(\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{x_3}\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x_1^3 \left(\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{x_3}\right)^2}
$$

What can you find?